# offline maps for C# app

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, maps, offline

I need some help regarding an app dev for desktop. Here are the things I require if any one can guide me here:

- In which format do I need to have the map of my country for embedding it in C# form App? I have these available:  " .osm.pbf " or " .shp.zip "
- I want to embed it in a C# form application in which I can enter coordinates of a location and the map should be directed towards it.

I have searched well before posting here but I am very new to C# dev and this stuff, I did not get them well enough or not upto my requirements.
Any guideline will help a lot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you had a look here [OsmSharp](https://github.com/OsmSharp) 
This is an open source project for handling open street map data in c# applications. You mentioned that you have your data in .osm.pbf format. Without knowing details, this framework should provide you with the necessary functionality to work with your data.

This link [OpenStreetMap Frameworks](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks) is a list of (all) open street map Frameworks. Good for overview. There is only one other c# framework: CartoType.

Comment: Can you kindly explain 2-3 lines about what it offers, currently I'am unable to figure out. it is way too broad.

Comment: sure. i added a few more lines :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Makielski. The first link you mentioned directs me to to list of things, assuming I have to go in OSMSharp? If yes then isn't there any downloadable application or something? The data I told you about is just a map that I downloaded from here: http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/pakistan.html , What I need is now just a way I can embed it into my simple C# app and then give it a cordinate and it places a marker or anything there.